# Postgres LIKE unique constraint possible?

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint

I'm new to Postgres and am creating a table (`metrics_reaches`) using pgAdmin III.

In my table, I have an `insertion_timestamp` of **timestamp with timezome** type column.

I'd like to create a `UNIQUE` constraint that, amongst other fields, checks only the date portion of the `insertion_timestamp` and not the time.

Is there a way to do that? Here's what my script looks like at the moment (see the last `CONSTRAINT`).

```
-- Table: metrics_reaches

-- DROP TABLE metrics_reaches;

CREATE TABLE metrics_reaches
(
  organizations_id integer NOT NULL,
  applications_id integer NOT NULL,
  countries_id integer NOT NULL,
  platforms_id integer NOT NULL,
  ...
  insertion_timestamp timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  id serial NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT metrics_reaches_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT metrics_reaches_applications_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (applications_id)
      REFERENCES applications (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT metrics_reaches_countries_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (countries_id)
      REFERENCES countries (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT metrics_reaches_organizations_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (organizations_id)
      REFERENCES organizations (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT metrics_reaches_platforms_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (platforms_id)
      REFERENCES platforms (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT metrics_reaches_organizations_id_key UNIQUE (organizations_id, applications_id, countries_id, platforms_id, insertion_timestamp)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE metrics_reaches
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a CAST():

```
CONSTRAINT metrics_reaches_organizations_id_key UNIQUE (
  organizations_id, 
  applications_id, 
  countries_id, 
  platforms_id, 
  CAST(insertion_timestamp AS date)
)
```

Comment: Comment on Frank's answer wouldn't fit here, so posted as separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a comment to Frank's answer, but it's too long for the comment box.

If you are being paranoid, you need to watch the local timezone carefully when dealing with date casts:

```
bookings=> SET timezone='GMT';
SET
bookings=> SELECT now() at time zone 'GMT', (now() at time zone 'GMT')::date, now(), now()::date;
         timezone          |  timezone  |             now              |    now     
---------------------------+------------+------------------------------+------------
 2013-05-30 19:36:04.23684 | 2013-05-30 | 2013-05-30 19:36:04.23684+00 | 2013-05-30
(1 row)

bookings=> set timezone='GMT-7';
SET
bookings=> SELECT now() at time zone 'GMT', (now() at time zone 'GMT')::date, now(), now()::date;
          timezone          |  timezone  |              now              |    now     
----------------------------+------------+-------------------------------+------------
 2013-05-30 19:36:13.723558 | 2013-05-30 | 2013-05-31 02:36:13.723558+07 | 2013-05-31
```

Now, PG is smart enough to know this is a problem, and if you try to create a constraint with a date cast then you should see something like:

```
ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE
```

If you try to cast after applying "at time zone" then it really is immutable and you can have your constraint.

Of course the other option is to wrap the cast in a function and mark the function as immutable. If you're going to lie to the system like that though, don't come complaining when your database behaves oddly a year from now.